# Ошибка приведения типов на момент исполнения программы

Tags: java

Знаю, что приведение типов может выдавать ошибку не во время компиляции, а уже после компиляции во время исполнения программы. Почему так происходит?
`A a = (A) b;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Компилятор не всегда может заранее узнать, какой класс приводится. Например:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    A a = new B();
    C c = (C) a;
}


static class A{}
static class B extends A{}
static class C extends A{}
```

}

[Данный код](https://ideone.com/tOO2UZ) во время выполнения выкинет `ClassCastException`. Код скомпилируется, потому что в объект класса `A` может являться объектом одним из дочерних классов, но проверить, какой конкретно тип у объекта можно только во время выполнения.

Вот более явный [пример](https://ideone.com/FKNkdY):

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    A a = sc.nextInt() == 1 ? new B() : new C();
    C c = (C) a;
}


static class A{}
static class B extends A{}
static class C extends A{}
```

Тут компилятор никак заранее не поймёт, можно ли привести тип.